# "Triple Join"?? Can an INNER-JOIN have have an add'l query after 'WHERE' to exclude rows from a 3rd table?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

Ok this (truncated query) runs fine. Got some expert advice a month ago to fix it.

```
SELECT * FROM artWork WHERE art_id in (
    SELECT art_id FROM artWork AS a INNER JOIN userPrefs AS u ON ((
      ((u.media_oil='1' AND a.media_oil='1') OR 
       (u.media_acrylic='1' AND a.media_acrylic='1') OR 
       (u.media_wc='1' AND a.media_wc='1') OR 
       (u.media_pastel='1' AND a.media_pastel='1')) 

       etc, etc........................................

   WHERE a.artist_id NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM removeList AS r 
        WHERE r.artist_id = a.artist_id 
          AND r.user_id ='$user_id') 
          AND  a.make_avail='1' 
          AND a.cur_select='1' 
          AND u.user_id='$user_id' 
          AND ((u.pref_painting='1' AND a.pref_painting='1') OR 
               (u.pref_photo='1' AND a.pref_photo='1') OR 
               (u.pref_paper='1' AND a.pref_paper='1') OR 
               (u.pref_print='1' AND a.pref_print='1') OR 
               (u.pref_draw='1' AND a.pref_draw='1') OR 
               (u.pref_sculp='1' AND a.pref_sculp='1') OR 
               (u.pref_install='1' AND a.pref_install='1') OR 
               (u.pref_vid='1' AND a.pref_vid='1') OR 
               (u.pref_public='1' AND a.pref_public='1') OR 
               (u.pref_indef='1' AND a.pref_indef='1'))
    ) ORDER BY date_submit DESC
```

But now I need to exclude certain rows that may be in another 2 column (user_id & artist_id) child table: 'removeList'. So I am trying without success to what amounts to a "triple join" (look for the code around 'NOT EXISTS'):

```
SELECT * FROM artWork WHERE  art_id in (
    SELECT art_id FROM artWork AS a INNER JOIN userPrefs AS u ON ( 
             (((u.media_oil='1' AND a.media_oil='1') OR 
               (u.media_acrylic='1' AND a.media_acrylic='1') OR 
               (u.media_wc='1' AND a.media_wc='1') OR 
               (u.media_pastel='1' AND a.media_pastel='1')) 

               etc, etc........................................


    WHERE a.artist_id NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM removeList AS r 
        WHERE r.artist_id = a.artist_id AND r.user_id ='$user_id'
    ) 
    AND  a.make_avail='1' 
    AND a.cur_select='1' 
    AND u.user_id='$user_id' 
    AND (( u.pref_painting='1' AND a.pref_painting='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_photo='1' AND a.pref_photo='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_paper='1' AND a.pref_paper='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_print='1' AND a.pref_print='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_draw='1' AND a.pref_draw='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_sculp='1' AND a.pref_sculp='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_install='1' AND a.pref_install='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_vid='1' AND a.pref_vid='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_public='1' AND a.pref_public='1') OR 
         ( u.pref_indef='1' AND a.pref_indef='1') )  
    ) ORDER BY date_submit DESC
```

Am I reaching too far here? Is there a better approach I am overlooking. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT EXISTS shouldn't have a column name before it.  remove the a.artist_id from before the not exists.

So the relevant line would say

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM removeList AS r 
    WHERE r.artist_id = a.artist_id AND r.user_id ='$user_id'
)
```

Not sure where you're using this query, but its also recommended to parameterize your queries to prevent sql injections.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Worked on the first shot. Also, fyi, not shown is that the entire query is saved to a variable and used to pull rows in standard fashion to echo in a dynamic list. This is the second time you've made my code behave. really appreciate it, ehudokai

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not an answer, but i could not place a table within the comments so i am putting it here.

i feel like extra tables to hold your media and prefs is needed here to greatly simplify things in your database.

```
media_table
id, user_id, media_type

prefs_table
id, user_id, pref_type
```

Then fields in your art table that correlate to a media type, and pref type.

```
art_table
media_type, art_type
```

This way you could easily use a simple JOIN to find correlating records instead of those hundreds of comparisons.

```
SELECT art.id FROM art JOIN prefs_table ON art.pref_type = prefs_table.pref_type JOIN users ON prefs_table.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = whatever
```

This is a simplified example that would pull up all peices of art that matched any one of the user's preferences. You could of course easily incorporate media types as well into the same query in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some serious work on your schema, along the lines suggested by [dqhendricks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512922/dqhendricks).

You have 3 tables:

- ArtWork (Art_ID, Artist_ID, ...characteristics...)
- UserPrefs (User_ID, ...characteristics...)
- RemoveList (Artist_ID, User_ID)

You want to list art works which match the user preferences of a specific user, but do not want to list any art works where the artist dislikes the user or the user dislikes the artist (or both).

You should, therefore, be able to do something like:

```
SELECT A.*
  FROM ArtWork   AS A
  JOIN UserPrefs AS U
    ON (U.User_ID = ? AND (...ghastly OR'd join conditions...))
 WHERE A.Artist_ID NOT IN (SELECT R.Artist_ID
                             FROM RemoveList AS R
                            WHERE R.User_ID = ?)
```

Note that you can move some of the join conditions into the WHERE clause, and various other changes, but the basic structure of the query will be a JOIN of ArtWork and UserPrefs and a WHERE clause with the NOT IN clause (which you could write as a NOT EXISTS clause, but I think the NOT IN formulation is easier to read).